# Which form of Latin pronunciation is most widely taught?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, ecclesiastical-latin

There are two popular versions of Latin pronunciation currently: the Ecclesiastical Pronunciation and the Classical Pronunciation. EP follows the rules of Italian pronunciation (has soft c and g) while the latter has no soft c and g. Out of these, which form is more widely used? The Classical form or the Italian-like form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Croatia, we were taught some other system of pronunciation: one without geminate consonants and with a soft 'c' but no soft 'g'. As far as I know, just about every country in Europe has its own traditional way of pronouncing Latin. But when you talk in Latin internationally, you are using some semi-classical pronunciation (I say "semi-" because, first of all, we don't know for certain how Latin was pronounced in ancient times), like the one I was using in [my video about afterlife in Latin](https://youtube.com/watch?v=gx1hhczsdAE&feature=share).

Comment: Classical Latin had no soft C or G.

Comment: @AkshatGoswami I didn't claim it had. I said the form of Latin taught in Croatian high-schools has a soft 'c' but no soft 'g'.

Comment: I have a recollection of hearing that the Jesuits have (or had) there own pronunciation. See [this article](https://wdtprs.com/2011/02/quaeritur-do-i-have-to-use-ecclesiastical-pronunciation-of-latin/) - Daniel Latinus's comment about half way down the blog page.

Comment: "When you talk in Latin internationally, you are using some semi-classical pronunciation...." This feels vague and mostly untrue: ecclesiastical Latin *is* international, albeit (usually) used only in certain liturgical contexts. I think you're right, though, that classical pronunciation is more common, particularly in secular contexts.

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly where you are learning Latin from. If you are following a curriculum that is for biblical studies, you are almost certainly learning ecclesiastical pronounciation.

Comment: This answer is a bit like: Who sells more cars, BMW or Toyota? — Depends on where exactly you are buying your car. At a BMW dealership, you are almost certainly buying a BMW.

Comment: @SK: Not really.

Answer (score 0):

In Poland we learn different kind of latin pronunciation that is based on both classical latin and german pronunciation of latin. So "c" is pronounced as "ts" or "k" but never "tch", "qu" and "gu" are pronounced with "v". I think teachers should teach either classical or ecclesiastical pronunciation instead of those national adaptations.

Comment: Classical Latin is actually the most common version of Latin.